# Reference a component function name as a callback from outside the component

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm trying to implement a basic Google Login in Vue3 SFC, using the Google API. The Google login code is this HTML:

```
<component src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" :is="'script'"></component>

  <div id="g_id_onload"
       data-client_id="454813487606-q3gep6aurieacd3kj02upb6fcfh2sqqb"
       data-callback="handleCredentialResponse">
  </div>
  <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard"></div>
```

The value of the `data-callback` attribute identifies the function to call after a successful Google login, in this case the function `handleCredentialResponse`.

I've defined the callback function `handleCredentialResponse` in the script setup code as follows:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import { authStore } from '@/stores/authStore';
import { User } from '@/stores/authStore';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

const router = useRouter();
const auth = authStore()

function handleCredentialResponse(googleUser: any) {

  fetch('https://localhost:7237/myApi/ValidateToken?token=' + googleUser.credential, {        
    method: "GET",          
  })
  .then(response => {
      return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
      auth.user = new User("Mr Test", data.token);
      router.push(auth.returnUrl)
  })
}

</script>
```

The callback function `handleCredentialResponse` is never called. I can get the callback to work correctly if I define `handleCredentialResponse` in the index.html file, but in that case I don't have access to the store or router.

I've tried adding `defineExpose({handleCredentialResponse})` but that didn't work.

I assume I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: not really a vue3 misunderstanding. you can add `globalThis.handleCredentialResponse = handleCredentialResponse` after you declare the function - that *may* help at least to get the function into the global scope

Comment: @JaromandaX This has done it, much appreciated. The code that I used is `(globalThis as any).handleCredentialResponse = handleCredentialResponse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment by JaromandaX, the solution was to add this line to bring the function in question into the global scope:

```
(globalThis as any).handleCredentialResponse = handleCredentialResponse
```